# Flash change frame on hittest

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, movieclip, hittest

This code is on my car movieclip called **car1**, this drives over a square movieclip called **LapChange**. I have a movieclip called **LapPlayer1** with 3 frames, each with a diffrent lap number on, this is the code im using to change the frame when the car goes over but with no luck, any ideas?

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){

if(this.hitTest(_root.LapChange)){


    if(_root.LapPlayer1.currentFrame == 1){

        _root.LapPlayer1.gotoAndStop(2);
    }

    if(_root.LapPlayer1.currentFrame == 2){

        _root.LapPlayer1.gotoAndStop(3);

    } 

    if(_root.LapPlayer1.currentFrame == 3){

        _root.LapPlayer1.gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentFrame` is ActionScript 3.0

In ActionScript **2.0**, you have to use `_currentframe`

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){

if(this.hitTest(_root.LapChange)){


    if(_root.LapPlayer1._currentframe == 1){

        _root.LapPlayer1.gotoAndStop(2);
    }

    if(_root.LapPlayer1._currentframe == 2){

        _root.LapPlayer1.gotoAndStop(3);

    } 

    if(_root.LapPlayer1._currentframe == 3){

        _root.LapPlayer1.gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
}
```